# Python: Adding to dict of one object in a list changes all dicts of every other object in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Python isn't my strong suit and I've encountered what I view to be a strange issue. I've narrowed the problem down to a few lines of code, simplifying it to make asking this question easier. I have a list of objects, this object:

```
class FinalRecord():
     ruid = 0
     drugs = {}
```

I create them in the shell like this:

```
finalRecords = []
fr = FinalRecord()
fr.ruid = 7
finalRecords.append(fr)
fr2 = FinalRecord()
fr2.ruid = 10
finalRecords.append(fr2)
```

As soon as I want to change the drugs dict on one object, it changes it for the other one too

```
finalRecords[0].drugs["Avonex"] = "Found"
```

I print out this:

```
finalRecords[1].drugs
```

and it shows:

```
{'Avonex':'Found'}
```

When I'm expecting it to actually be empty. I know I'm not completely understand how Python is working with the objects, can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is because `drugs` is a class attribute. So if you change it for one object it will in fact change in others.

If you are looking to not have this behaviour, then you are looking for instance attributes. Set drugs in your `__init__` like this:

```
class FinalRecord():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ruid = 0
        self.drugs = {}
```

Take note of the use of `self`, which is a reference to your object.

Here is some info on [class vs instance attributes](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php)

So, full demo illustrating this behaviour:

```
>>> class FinalRecord():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.ruid = 0
...         self.drugs = {}
...
>>> obj1 = FinalRecord()
>>> obj2 = FinalRecord()
>>> obj1.drugs['stuff'] = 2
>>> print(obj1.drugs)
{'stuff': 2}
>>> print(obj2.drugs)
{}
```

Comment: Ah, I got ya, I didn't quite understand how classes worked in Python

Comment: Basically methods (the def keyword) and variables declared at the class scope (indended one level up from the class keyword) are defining elements in a dictionary, that dictionary is your class.  Some of the elements are functions (def) and others are class fields. Once you get the Dynamic nature of Python, a lot of things will make sense all at once.

Comment: @SpencerSutton: You should consider accepting this answer if it actually helped you solve your problem.

Comment: it might have been six years, but you, Sir, just rescued me from a two day nightmare with that simple, but important answer

Answer (score 1):

You define `drugs` as a *class* attribute, not an instance attribute.  Because of that, you are always modifying the same object.  You should instead define `drugs` in the `__init__` method.  I would also suggest using `ruid` as an argument:

```
class FinalRecord():
    def __init__(self, ruid):
        self.ruid = ruid
        self.drugs = {}
```

It could then be used as this:

```
fr = FinalRecord(7)
finalRecords.append(fr)
fr2 = FinalRecord(10)
finalRecords.append(fr2)
```

Or more simply:

```
finalRecords.append(FinalRecord(7))
finalRecords.append(FinalRecord(10))
```